# How to Get Access to a Map been used in ArcGIS Online App

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Can someone tell how I can access to GDB/ ArcGIS Online Map/ or ArcGIS Server service of the Map been used in this App (`https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Cascade/index.html?appid=e8a78203d79042acbec87255d45e6ab9`)?

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="800px" src="https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Cascade/index.html?appid=e8a78203d79042acbec87255d45e6ab9" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

I need to get the Network assets/ Not sure this is been made using  Utility or Gematric Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first map inside the story map one can extract the service URL using the network analysis tools inside your browser. This yields the following URL:

https://services1.arcgis.com/36PP9fe9l4BSnArw/arcgis/rest/services/ElectricDistributionLine/FeatureServer/0/

This can be loaded inside ArcGIS or QGIS as a FeatureServer. If it is not disabled you can also download it from inside your GIS. Another method would be to query the complete layer inside the REST API. If you need all the services hosted by the server you can see them here:

https://services1.arcgis.com/36PP9fe9l4BSnArw/arcgis/rest/services/

Comment: Thanks Carlos but can you also let me know why I am not seeing any of those symbology at the services?

Comment: Can you also give me a hint on how to access to "network analysis tools inside browser"? thanks

Comment: For the network analysis tools simply press F12 and select 'network' (might be a different terminology depending on your browser). The symbology is defined on the 'web map' level. The predefined symbology of the layers inside the service are kept rather simple. You can see one symbology definition when viewing this link: https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/cbae9b4dddae47e78678ea83675e0357/data?f=json